# Express readFile html and replace string return blank page

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using `fs.readFile` API from Express to read html file and I want to replace string within html file, but it's returning a blank page on client side.
My directory structure is:

```
// ===== directory ===== //
rootDir
    dist/
        index.html
index.js
package.json

// ==== package.json ==== //
{
  "name": "express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}

// ==== dist/index.html ======//
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>


// ==== index.js ==== //
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('dist'));

fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'), (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const lorem = 'lorem ipsum';
    const test = data.toString().replace('<div id="app"></div>', `<div id="app">${lorem}</div>`)

    // doing console.log for testing
    console.log(test)

    // returning variable
    // return test
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html')
})

app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    console.log(`listening port ${PORT}`);
})
```

When I `return test` in `index.js` I got blank screen in client side, so I use `console.log(test)` to check whether the DOM was properly replaced or not.

Here is the output from `console.log(test)`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">lorem ipsum</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nothing error, but why I got a blank page? Any suggestions or help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, when you do `fs.readFile`, you don't store the result anywhere. When you `return test;`, the value goes nowhere.

To solve your problem, remove this useless `fs.readFile` part and instead specify `dist/index.html' in your router, like this:

```
// ==== index.js ==== //
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(PORT, error => {
  console.log(`listening port ${PORT}`);
});
```

This should work fine.